# Removing array items with no value with javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a variable that looks like this:

```
["something here", "", "something else here", ""]
```

As you can see there are a empty entries.

I need to remove them so that the array contains no empty entries.

How can I do this?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the Array filter method. `filter(Boolean)` filters all falsy items.

```js
['',null,0,1].filter(Boolean) // [1]
```

```js
const arr = ["something here", "", "something else here", ""];
const newArr = arr.filter(Boolean);
console.log(newArr);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter()` and check `length` of `string`

```js
let arr =["something here", "", "something else here", ""];
console.log(arr.filter(a => a.length))
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code

```
let array ="something here", "", "something else here", ""];
array.forEach((item,index)=>{
    if(item===""){
        array.splice(index,1);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a method in JavaScript called *filter*. This method is responsible to literally filter which values you want (or not).

In this case, maybe you can use the following approach:

```
var filtered = ["something here", "", "something else here", ""].filter(function(item) {
   return item != "";
});
```

The *filtered* variable will have the result:

```
["something here", "something else here"]
```

Answer (score 0):

One last option, similar to the Boolean one, is a basic filter returning the element if the element is not null, but I personnaly find it more explicit than Boolean:

```
 let array = ['hi', 'this', '', 'is', 'a', '', 'demo']
 let filteredArray = array.filter(str => str)
// filteredArray will be equal to ['hi', 'this', 'is', 'a', 'demo']
```